# CCSequence actionsWithArray: is deprecated

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am wondering why CCSequence actionsWithArray: is deprecated and how to fix that.  Any help that you can give would be appreciated.

Comment: see ccDeprecated.h/.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, LearnCocos2D.  The answer was in ccDeprecated.h.  Turns out, all you need to do is use [CCSequence actionWithArray:] instead of actionsWithArray: